Unable to create/open Word documents Windows 10
I was trying to clear up storage space on my computer and accidentally deleted something. I now seem to be unable to create Word documents, and the ones I have are all grayed out and ask me "how I want to open this file", with no option for Word. How do I fix this?
 
It still shows when I search for it, but I am unable to open Word. And if it matters, yes I seem to have and am able to open wordPAD, but obviously do not wish to use that.

I also reinstalled Office as instructed, but it still does not seem to let me make Word documents.


Did you by chance remove Wordpad? I assume by “Word” you actually meant Wordpad. I also assume you are using Windows 10 and not Windows 11 24H2

Yes I am using windows 10, and I do seem to be able to open docx files with wordpad.

Try reinstalling Office.

I had to reinstall office 365, but not from the Microsoft store, that one did not work.
